# How to intercept opening sms message inbox?

Tags: java, android

is it possible to intercept user opening sms message inbox. I would like to provide auth mechanism on that event so you can protect your sms inbox from being opened without permission.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understand your question, do you want to in a sense password protect the Inbox?  If so then I think most phones have this option by default, also the Java App would need to be running each time the user opens the Inbox, in most phone J2ME apps can't keep running like that... As far as I am aware.

Comment: FYI android is not a J2ME platform.

Comment: @Chris Stratton my bad, I didn't see that this was in the Android section.

Answer (score 0):

Disregarding if it  is or isn't possible, if you just installed a gatekeeper type of application an attacker could simply uninstall that application, something there is no means for an ordinary application to prevent.

So I believe you would have to remove the SMS from the default storage and keep them in storage of your password-protected application. That way if your application is uninstalled the stored SMS are also removed.  You might also want to encrypt the storage to provide some degree of protection against someone rooting the device and gaining the ability to read the application's private storage.  They would of course still be able to uninstall the application and read any newly received SMS.

Answer (score 0):

> is it possible to intercept user opening sms message inbox

No, sorry.